# Appending Array values next to each other in Perl

Tags: perl, scripting

I have two arrays: `@devicedat` and `@timestamp` in below way.

#### `@timestamp`

```
 Nov 20 21:58:41 PST 2016
 Nov 20 21:59:11 PST 2016
 Nov 20 21:59:41 PST 2016
```

#### `@devicedat`

```
 sda              28.00     0.00 10.00  0.00   156.00     0.00    31.20     0.04    3.70   3.60   3.60
 sda1              0.00     0.00  0.00  0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
 sda2             28.00     0.00  4.00  0.00   128.00     0.00    64.00     0.03    6.50   6.50   2.60
 sda3              0.00     0.00  6.00  0.00    28.00     0.00     9.33     0.01    1.83   1.67   1.00
 sdb               0.00     0.00  0.00  2.00     0.00     8.00     8.00     0.00    0.50   0.50   0.10
 sdb1              0.00     0.00  0.00  2.00     0.00     8.00     8.00     0.00    0.50   0.50   0.10
 sdc               0.00     0.00 1351.00  0.00  5404.00     0.00     8.00     0.76    0.56   0.56  76.00
 sdc1              0.00     0.00 1351.00  0.00  5404.00     0.00     8.00     0.76    0.56   0.56  76.00
 sda               0.00     0.00 14.00  0.00    56.00     0.00     8.00     0.01    0.50   0.50   0.70
 sda1              0.00     0.00  0.00  0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
 sda2              0.00     0.00  0.00  0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
 sda3              0.00     0.00 14.00  0.00    56.00     0.00     8.00     0.01    0.50   0.50   0.70
 sdb               0.00     0.00 89.00  0.00   356.00     0.00     8.00     0.14    1.52   1.52  13.50
 sdb1              0.00     0.00 89.00  0.00   356.00     0.00     8.00     0.14    1.52   1.52  13.50
 sdc               0.00     0.00 513.00  0.00  2052.00     0.00     8.00     0.75    1.45   1.46  74.70
 sdc1              0.00     0.00 513.00  0.00  2052.00     0.00     8.00     0.75    1.45   1.46  74.70
```

I want to append the timestamp to each of the Disk in Perl and  need output as below:

```
Nov 20 21:58:41 PST 2016,sda 28.00 0.00 10.00 0.00 156.00 0.00 31.20 0.04 3.70 3.60 3.60
Nov 20 21:58:41 PST 2016, sda1.....
Nov 20 21:58:41 PST 2016, sda2.....
Nov 20 21:58:41 PST 2016, sda3.....
Nov 20 21:58:41 PST 2016, sdb......
Nov 20 21:58:41 PST 2016, sdb1.....
Nov 20 21:58:41 PST 2016, sdc......
Nov 20 21:58:41 PST 2016, sdc1.....
Nov 20 21:59:11 PST 2016, sda......
Nov 20 21:59:11 PST 2016, sda1.....
Nov 20 21:59:11 PST 2016, sda2.....
Nov 20 21:59:11 PST 2016, sda3.....
Nov 20 21:59:11 PST 2016, sdb......
Nov 20 21:59:11 PST 2016, sdb1.....
```

How to append the values in above way in Perl? I want the values appended to time stamp for all disks to interpret the Device Data in CSV format.

Comment: Hi Alexander, Sorry I'm very new to perl and i have a gz file with iostat output from OS Watcher. I'm using below lines to keep the arrays time stamp and Devicedata.
@devicedat = `zcat xyz.xyz.com_iostat_16.11.20.2100.dat.gz | grep ^sd | sort -s--n -k1,1`;
@timestamp = `zcat $file | grep zzz | cut -d" " -f3-7`;
So I'm looking for a function or command that can do the append as required.

Comment: If the problem is that you don't know Perl then the solution is in your hands. We can't really help with that.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is called a [Cartesian Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product). You have to nest the iterators for each set within each other, like so:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @timestamp = (
    'Nov 20 21:58:41 PST 2016',
    'Nov 20 21:59:11 PST 2016',
    'Nov 20 21:59:41 PST 2016',
);

my @devicedat = (
    'sda    28.00     0.00   10.00  0.00   156.00     0.00    31.20     0.04    3.70   3.60   3.60',
    'sda1    0.00     0.00    0.00  0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00',
    'sda2   28.00     0.00    4.00  0.00   128.00     0.00    64.00     0.03    6.50   6.50   2.60',
    'sda3    0.00     0.00    6.00  0.00    28.00     0.00     9.33     0.01    1.83   1.67   1.00',
    'sdb     0.00     0.00    0.00  2.00     0.00     8.00     8.00     0.00    0.50   0.50   0.10',
    'sdb1    0.00     0.00    0.00  2.00     0.00     8.00     8.00     0.00    0.50   0.50   0.10',
    'sdc     0.00     0.00 1351.00  0.00  5404.00     0.00     8.00     0.76    0.56   0.56  76.00',
    'sdc1    0.00     0.00 1351.00  0.00  5404.00     0.00     8.00     0.76    0.56   0.56  76.00',
    'sda     0.00     0.00   14.00  0.00    56.00     0.00     8.00     0.01    0.50   0.50   0.70',
    'sda1    0.00     0.00    0.00  0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00',
    'sda2    0.00     0.00    0.00  0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00',
    'sda3    0.00     0.00   14.00  0.00    56.00     0.00     8.00     0.01    0.50   0.50   0.70',
    'sdb     0.00     0.00   89.00  0.00   356.00     0.00     8.00     0.14    1.52   1.52  13.50',
    'sdb1    0.00     0.00   89.00  0.00   356.00     0.00     8.00     0.14    1.52   1.52  13.50',
    'sdc     0.00     0.00  513.00  0.00  2052.00     0.00     8.00     0.75    1.45   1.46  74.70',
    'sdc1    0.00     0.00  513.00  0.00  2052.00     0.00     8.00     0.75    1.45   1.46  74.70',
);

my @product = ();
for my $timestamp ( @timestamp ){
    for my $devicedat ( @devicedat ){
        push @product, "$timestamp, $devicedat";
    }
}

print "$_\n" for @product;
```

More details on [Cartesian Product in Perl](https://lookatperl.blogspot.ca/2012/12/a-look-at-cartesian-products.html).

Comment: i tried foreach loop but i dont need one time stamp to all devices in devicedata array. It should go to first 6 disks and 2nd time stamp should be printed when sda starts for 2nd time in devicedat array.